# OpenCL does not detect Xeon Phi

Tags: opencl, xeon-phi

We created a small program to detect Xeon Phi, here is our code snippet

```
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platformList(5);
    std::vector<cl::Device> deviceList;
    cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
    if(platformList.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "No Platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<platformList.size(); i++){
    // for(i=0; i<1; i++){
            std::cout << platformList[i].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<< std::endl;
            platformList[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &deviceList);
            if(deviceList.size() == 0){
                    std::cout << "No Devices found. Check OpenCL installation!" << std::endl;
                    exit(1);
            }

            for(j=0; j<deviceList.size(); j++){
                    // dims = deviceList[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
                    // for(k=0; k<dims.size(); k++)
                    // std::cout << dims[k] << std::endl;
                    std::cout << deviceList[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<< std::endl;
            }
    }

    cl::Device device = deviceList[j-1];

    std::cout << "Using device: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;
```

but it does not detect the Phi, we get only this output;

```
    Intel(R) OpenCL
      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Using device:       Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Hello World
```

Do you know what are we doing wrong?

P.S. Below can you find micinfo output

```
    MicInfo Utility Log
Copyright 2011-2013 Intel Corporation All Rights Reserved.

Created Thu Oct  2 15:04:08 2014


    System Info
        HOST OS         : Linux
        OS Version      : 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
        Driver Version      : 3.2-1
        MPSS Version        : 3.2
        Host Physical Memory    : 16274 MB

Device No: 0, Device Name: mic0

    Version
        Flash Version        : 2.1.02.0390
        SMC Firmware Version     : 1.16.5078
        SMC Boot Loader Version  : 1.8.4326
        uOS Version          : 2.6.38.8+mpss3.2
        Device Serial Number     : ADKC32800437

    Board
        Vendor ID        : 0x8086
        Device ID        : 0x225d
        Subsystem ID         : 0x3608
        Coprocessor Stepping ID  : 2
        PCIe Width       : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Speed       : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Max payload size    : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Max read req size   : Insufficient Privileges
        Coprocessor Model    : 0x01
        Coprocessor Model Ext    : 0x00
        Coprocessor Type     : 0x00
        Coprocessor Family   : 0x0b
        Coprocessor Family Ext   : 0x00
        Coprocessor Stepping     : C0
        Board SKU        : C0PRQ-3120/3140 P/A
        ECC Mode         : Enabled
        SMC HW Revision      : Product 300W Active CS

    Cores
        Total No of Active Cores : 57
        Voltage          : 0 uV
        Frequency        : 1100000 kHz

    Thermal
        Fan Speed Control    : On
        Fan RPM          : 1200
        Fan PWM          : 20
        Die Temp         : 45 C

    GDDR
        GDDR Vendor      : Elpida
        GDDR Version         : 0x1
        GDDR Density         : 2048 Mb
        GDDR Size        : 5952 MB
        GDDR Technology      : GDDR5 
        GDDR Speed       : 5.000000 GT/s 
        GDDR Frequency       : 2500000 kHz
        GDDR Voltage         : 1501000 uV
```

Comment: Did you install the OpenCL driver for Phi? What does `micinfo` say?

Comment: I have uptated the post and put information about micinfo's output

Comment: I suggest you run a `strace` on your program and check that the OpenCL MIC drivers are properly loaded. (`libmic_device.so` and `libcoi_host.so`).

Comment: I get some errors like open("/usr/lib64/libmic_device.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) , so it seems the OpenCL MIC drivers are not installed. What is the best way to do it in CentOS ?

Comment: You may [follow the Intel guidelines](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-xe-2013-release-notes)

Comment: I get that "Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 package opencl-1.2-base-1:4.4.0.117-1.x86_64 is already installed
 package opencl-1.2-intel-cpu-1:4.4.0.117-1.x86_64 is already installed", so probably they were not installed properly?

Comment: Yes, you probably have a problem with your installation. There's not much I can do. Find where the drivers got installed and/or attempt to fix your install, somehow.

Comment: Those are just the base and CPU packages, you also need to install the Xeon Phi OpenCL runtime: opencl-1.2-intel-mic-4.5.0.8-1.x86_64.rpm. If you grab the latest driver package, there's a handy install script to sort all this out for you: http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/4181/opencl_runtime_14.2_x64_4.5.0.8.tgz

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-runtime-release-notes. It is more recent than the page Cicada pointed you to and provides a link to Intel® OpenCL™ Runtime 14.2.

The libmic_device.so is included with the OpenCL runtime and is, by default, in /opt/intel/opencl{version_number}/lib64. You will want to make sure that path is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. You will also want to make sure that /opt/intel/opencl{version_number}/mic is in your MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

You already have the Intel MPSS installed; otherwise micinfo would not work. The libcoi_host.so is included in the MPSS and installs in /usr/lib64, which is already in your library search path.

The version of the MPSS that you are running is 3.2-1. The "What's new" notes for the OpenCL runtime 14.1 on the release notes web page says that version 14.1 is unstable under MPSS 3.2-1. I am trying to find out if there is a different version of the runtime you can use with MPSS 3.2-1 that is more stable or if the only recommendation is to install a newer MPSS. You can find the latest MPSS releases at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-manycore-platform-software-stack-mpss.